# How to use this IIS Express Config in Azure (Using Virtual Directories)

Tags: asp.net, api, azure-web-app-service, azure-pipelines, virtual-directory

Here is my IIS Express config.

```
<sites>
    <site name="Test.Web" id="1">
        <application path="/" applicationPool="Clr4IntegratedAppPool">
            <virtualDirectory path="/" physicalPath="C:\dev\test\Test.Web" />
        </application>
        <bindings>
            <binding protocol="http" bindingInformation="*:56428:localhost" />
        </bindings>
    </site>
    <site name="Test.Api" id="2">
        <application path="/" applicationPool="Clr4IntegratedAppPool">
            <virtualDirectory path="/" physicalPath="C:\dev\test\Test.Api" />
        </application>
        <application path="/Foo" applicationPool="Clr4IntegratedAppPool">
            <virtualDirectory path="/" physicalPath="C:\dev\test\Foo.Api" />
        </application>
        <bindings>
            <binding protocol="http" bindingInformation="*:51913:localhost" />
        </bindings>
    </site>
    <siteDefaults>
        <logFile logFormat="W3C" directory="%IIS_USER_HOME%\Logs" />
        <traceFailedRequestsLogging directory="%IIS_USER_HOME%\TraceLogFiles" enabled="true" maxLogFileSizeKB="1024" />
    </siteDefaults>
    <applicationDefaults applicationPool="Clr4IntegratedAppPool" />
    <virtualDirectoryDefaults allowSubDirConfig="true" />
</sites>
```

So what I want is a Web project (Test.Web), an API project (Test.API) and a sub API project (Foo.API).

This works locally where the Web project is available on port 56428, the API project is available on port 51913 and the sub API project is available on the same port if the /Foo prefix is used in the request.

Trying to configure azure so the Web project is deployed to `http://{web}.azurewebsites.net/`, and the API projects are deployed to `http://{api}.azurewebsites.net/`.

I accomplished this when I had just a Web project and an API project. But after adding a sub API project, all requests to the api server returns the default IIS 500 error (html page and all).

Here is my setup-

[image]
[image]
[image]

**UPDATE-**

I'm currently following this tutorial and just publishing through VS right now.

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/tomholl/2014/09/21/deploying-multiple-virtual-directories-to-a-single-azure-website/

My API project is being deployed to the same physical space as the web project and overwriting things like the Web.config. Does this have anything to do with using the "Basic" free-mo service plan?

**UPDATE UPDATE**

Managed to get publishing to work through VS. I'll update if I can replicate with automated deployments

Comment: What's the result now? Do you success deploying to virtual application of a app service?

Answer (score 0):

Refer to these steps to deploy app to virtual directory of a app service.

1. Create a virtual directory (Application settings>Virtual applications and directories)

[image]

2. Specify Virtual application for Azure App Service Deploy task.

[image]

Comment: Does the app service name need to be postfixed with `x/WebApi`?

Comment: No, just the virtual application name.